# Storing mobile number in Mysql with zero on the left

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried many ways to store mobile numbers to the database without losing the zero on left (0111…etc) but I couldn't.
The mobile field in the database is Varchar(20). The problem happens in both engines (MyISAM and InnoDB).
I tested the `$phone` (after validations and processing it) and `$_POST['phone']`, both of them print the zero, but after inserting the number into the tables it's lost.
Note: I use prepared statement with MySQLi, I tried to define the phone as string (s) and integer (i) in the `bind_param()`, however I face the same probelm.

Edited:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `ctitle` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `search` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `cat` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `country` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `phone2` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `website` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `uid` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to show the code you are using.  However, if the parameter is a string, and you assign it to a string in the database, I don't see how the leading zero could disappear.

Comment: if it's not storing the leading 0, you're not really storing it in a string field

Comment: @GordonLinoff The code is similar to this:

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, phone, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $phone, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

Comment: and your `show create table` is?

Comment: [that works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e6e/1). you really need to double check the values you are passing in.

Comment: The PHP code is similar to what you put in your comment. How similar? Can you edit your question with the exact PHP code?

Comment: varchar(20) is plenty according to ITU-T rec E.164. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164  You are *definitely* assigning the number to a numeric data item before you insert it into the data base column if you're losing a leading zero. It's probably a `double` item, because a typical 32-bit `int` overflows in the tenth digit. It's possible you're using 64-bit php on a 64-bit machine, though, in which case you can handle 20-digit integers.  To test, try formatting your phone number like +1.800.555.1212 or some such.

Comment: @pala_ Thank you for your help. I understand it's a weired problem. I check the phone value many times, even, I printed it before and after the insertion to database, and everything seems fine, the problem happens after the value go to the database. I will try one thing more, changing the machine I work on, maybe the it's localhost has a problem.

Comment: try inserting literal values and see if it makes a difference - ie, hard code the values into the query instead of using the form variables..

Comment: Another idea, try inserting letters as the phone number, like 'ABCDEFGHI' and see if you either get an error somewhere or it becomes 0. That would be further proof that it's being interpreted as a number somewhere along the way.

Comment: This could be one of PHP's unwanted times when it acts smart. Try with `$stmt->bind_param('s', (string)$phone);`